# 'openssl/evp.h' file not found OS x Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl, installation, pecl

Having a mare with this. I'm trying to install the latest PHP mongo DB Drivers. I've looked everywhere and tried everything suggested but it will not get passed this error:

---

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/src/contrib/php-ssl.c:31:
/private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/src/contrib/php-ssl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'openssl/evp.h' file not found
include <openssl/evp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/contrib/php-ssl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

---

My system / setup:

OS X El Capitain v 10.11.6
PHP 7.1.0
Apache

I'm using this command to install it: `sudo pecl install mongodb`

I've tried the:

```
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
```

but that no longer works...and any of the latest workarounds for that do not work either

I've even tried going "rootless" but to no avail.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out for a whole week over this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm still no further forward with this. Think I'm going to set up a dev server on a raspberry pi at this rate.

Comment: I ended up getting annoyed and completely removing my Apache and PHP installation, and then reinstalling. All good now

Comment: gave up...went back to ubuntu.

Comment: Solutions below didn't work for me. Running on Catalina 10.15.6

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[This solution](https://www.anintegratedworld.com/mac-osx-fatal-error-opensslsha-h-file-not-found/) worked for me. If you don't already have openssl then first run `brew install openssl`. 
Then run:

```
$ cd /usr/local/include 
$ ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .
```

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Worked for me on an unrelated build (promark3) which had the same error (`'openssl/evp.h' file not found`)

Answer (score 2):

Two things are required. The one suggested by @ierdna was what was required for me to work, but only after I performed the following

```
~$ brew install openssl
~$ brew info openssl
```

Do the exporting as told by brew

```
~$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
~$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Then do what ierdna tells you..

```
~$ cd /usr/local/include
~$ ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .
```

It worked for me immediately

Comment: please work on that edit queue